# DropBox API Invalid or missing signature

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm trying to enable dropbox manipulation via API provided in [DropBox series](http://cgeers.com/category/programming/dropbox/)

Here is the url generated:

**https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/sandbox/public/2WayServiceOverview.pdf?oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXX&oauth_nonce=5382801&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1354311566&oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=5ooZ4PP5V85bi28aI6pKQfahWpY%3d**

Of course some data I replaced to not share all :-)

Authorization passes, I get access code and then getting 
**{"error": "Invalid or missing signature"}**

File **public/2WayServiceOverview.pdf** exists for sure. What I am doing wrong? Is it maybe about oauth_signature_method?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using HTTPS, you can use the much simpler PLAINTEXT signature method.  For you, this means:

1. Set oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT
2. Set oauth_signature=urlencode(app_secret + "&" access_token_secret)

It might be easier to pass OAuth credentials via an HTTP header instead of via URL query parameters.  See point 4 of this article: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/20